# Excel VBA : Copy Range to a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel, range, copy-paste

I have the below code which was working an hour back and not working now suddenely :-(
Am I missing anything here?

```
 Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("P:\Env_Check_Report\Results\" & "ENV_Report_ORG.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=True)

    Set ReportWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("P:\Env_Check_Report\Results\" & "Report.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=True)

    ReportWorkbook.Sheet5.Range("B2:T10").Copy _
        Destination:=NewWorkbook.Sheet2.Range("B2:T10")
```

Comment: Whats the runtime error ? Which line gives the error ?

Comment: Object does not support this property or method is the error. Its throwing in up in the last line where I am copy pasting

Comment: What *part* of the line gives you the error? Is it `ReportWorkbook.Sheet5`? Or `ReportWorkbook.Sheet5.Range("B2:T10")`? Or `ReportWorkbook.Sheet5.Range("B2:T10").Copy`? Or... You get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
Dim xlObj As Object
Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set NewWorkbook = xlObj.Workbooks.Open("P:\Env_Check_Report\Results\" & "ENV_Report_ORG.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=True)

Set ReportWorkbook = xlObj.Workbooks.Open("P:\Env_Check_Report\Results\" & "Report.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=True)

Set NewWorksht = NewWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")
Set Reportsht = ReportWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

If Not NewWorkbook Is Nothing And Not ReportWorkbook Is Nothing Then
   NewWorksht.Range("B2:T10").Copy
   Reportsht.Range("B2:T10").PasteSpecial
End If
```

Comment: The Sheet is there. It is present as Sheet1(Sheet5) ..SO I tried it with Sheet1 as well...But still the same error

Comment: Tried with if loop as well..It s going inside the loop and give the same error at the line where we mentioned to copy

Comment: @sravs448 Add `ReportWorkbook.Activate` before copy and try again

Comment: I am having this code in excel macro...So I dont think we need the code like this..Its not VB...ITs an excel macro

Comment: @sravs448 Did you try it in excel ?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the first quote on the second line:

```
Set ReportWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("P:\Env_Check_Report\Results\" & "Report.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=True)
```

Comment: Sorry thats a typo..Its present there

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see where it errors?

Comment: Yep..its throwing run time error..Object does not support this property or method.

Comment: Is it possible to use the Sheets collection to reference the right sheet, rather than ActiveSheet?

Comment: What about `ReportWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Range(...`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & "\" & strFilename)

wbSrc.Worksheets(5).Range("B2:T10").Copy

Set wbDes = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath2 & "\" & strFilename2)     

wbDes.Worksheets(2).Range("B2:T10").Paste
```

You can also create a new workbook in your code with:

```
Set wbDes = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
```

Comment: Compile Error :Invalid or unqualified reference at WorkSheets(5).

Comment: @sravs448 did you update Worksheets(5) to reference your worksheet? (I assumed it was the 5th sheet but it might not be)